# How to perform a foreach in an associative array/object in a MongoDB schema instantiation using mongoose without selecting schema config parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Been Googling for hours and can't really find a solid answer. Maybe I'm using the wrong search parameters? Anyways here I go:

I'm new to MongoDB and am trying to change the values of a schema instantiation before I save it. I know there are a lot of posts on using the 'save' middleware, but I don't think it will solve my problem.

I have a schema design like this:

```
var fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data:{
        type1: {
            objectfoo: [],
            objectbar: []
        };
        type2: {
            objectxxx: [],
            objectyyy: []
        };
    }
});
```

This is not an infinite object, so I didn't want to do fancy stuff like link it to another schema or collection.

I want to do something like:

```
for(i in data){
    for(j in data[i]){
        data[i][j].push(val);
    }
}
```

However, it will give me an "undefined error" or will say object does not exist and error out. I did a `console.log` within the first for loop and it turns out that not only does for(...in...) selects the data fields, but it also selects the configuration fields within the schema instantiation like:

```
$__delta
$__version
increment
$__where
remove
model
$__buildDoc
init
$__storeShard
toJSON
[Function]
[Function]
```

So I guess the code works, it just breaks when it hits one of these other properties and tries to push a value in.

Note that "type1" and "objectfoo" need to be in an associative type of array because I need to refer to them by name, so I can't use a normal array and loop through `array.length`. I'm probably going about this completely wrong as I'm new to MongoDB so if there is a much more efficient way to do this, please do tell.

I'm thinking there's a way to refer to only the data field of the object without selecting the other configuration stuff but I can't find it after searching for a few hours.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For clarity: I've instantiated it already with:

```
var Foo = mongoose.model('foo', fooSchema);
var newfoo = new Foo();
```

So when I do:

```
for(i in newfoo.data){
    console.log(newfoo.data[i]);
}
```

It will print out all the configuration stuff.

Comment: Did you actually create a model from the schema? `var m = mongoose.Model('MyModel', fooSchema)`

Comment: Yes. Everything's created. Let me edit the post for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `toObject()` on your model data when you need to convert it to a plain object without any extra fields or functions:

```
for(i in data.toObject()){
    for(j in data[i].toObject()){
        data[i][j].push(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: toObject() did the trick. Thanks a lot. Is this a mongoose function or a javascript native function?

Comment: @PGT It's a Mongoose function, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: Thank you! this solved my issue of displaying the data using the Express handlebars